# Calculate $\int \frac{1}{(\sin (x)+\cos (x))^{100}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I would to calculate the following integral with different ways

$$\int \frac{1}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{100}}dx$$

My thoughts:

$\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\sqrt{2}\cos(x+\pi/4)$

Comment: Have you tried substitution? What about $u=\sin(x)$ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution ?

Comment: Different ways? Let us start with one. Since $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{2}\cos(x-\pi/4)$ the problem is equivalent to finding $$\int\frac{d\theta}{\cos^{100}\theta}.$$ By substituting $\theta=\arctan u$ we have that the problem boils down to computing a partial fraction decomposition / applying the binomial theorem.

Comment: There's a procedure for integrating positive integer powers of secant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed It will be tedious, though.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Jack D'Aurizio's comment below the OP, after the substitution, you wind up faced trying to integrate

$$\int{d\theta\over\cos^{100}\theta}=\int\sec^{98}\theta\sec^2\theta\, d\theta=\int(\tan^2\theta+1)^{49}\,d(\tan\theta)=\int(u^2+1)^{49}du=\cdots$$

This is clearly straightforward, but looks unpleasant. It might be worth experimenting with some smaller exponents, say $6$ instead of $100$, to see if the end result simplifies.

Comment: could you try it out 6 for example to see what's gonna happend